# Snapping two lines using Shapely

Tags: shapely, snapping, geopandas

I'm trying to snap two Linestrings shapefiles using Shapely/Geopandas. I tried :

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import *
from shapely.ops import snap

lines1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('lines1.shp')
lines1.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2227'})
lines2 =gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('lines2.shp')
lines2.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2227'})
res = snap(lines1, lines2, 10)
res.to_file('result.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

But I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Documents/script.py", line 14, in <module>
    res = snap(lines1, lines2, 10)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\shapely\ops.py", line 303, in snap
    return(geom_factory(lgeos.methods['snap'](g1._geom, g2._geom, tolerance)))
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2672, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute '_geom'

Process finished with exit code 1.
```

Any idea on what the problem is?

**EDIT :**

Updated code based on @caiohamamura's answer :

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import *
from shapely.ops import snap

lines1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('lines1.shp')
lines1 = lines1.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2227'})
lines2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('lines2.shp')
lines2 = lines2.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2227'})
res = lines1
lines2_union = lines2.geometry.unary_union
res.geometry = res.geometry.apply(lambda x: snap(x, lines2_union, 10))
res.to_file('result.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Now I have this error :

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I no longer get the above error. The script runs well, although the snapping doesn't seem to work that well. Here's an example of the result : 
[image: Snapping two lines]

The **blue** line is the **result** of the snapping

The **black** one is **lines2**

The **red** one is **lines1**

I tried changing the tolerance but it seems that if I give a value that's > to 15 feets I might get a wrong output.
The lines do not get snapped totally to each other. In some places they do, in others they don't as demonstrated on the screenshot above.

Comment: This should work, I've executed that for a sample data I have here and it works fine. At what specific command do you get the error? What coordinate system are you using? If it is lat/long 10 will actually mean(1110 km).

Comment: @caiohamamura I don't know at which specific command the error pops up now. This is the only shown message I get : Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
As for the coordinates system I'm not using WGS84, that's why I'm doing a transformation at the beginning to 2227 (projected coordinate system of SF)

Comment: I think this error code is due to the size of your shapefile. It stands for the classical stackoverflow error. So you need to increase stack size. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31902018/2548351). Also you can run the script in interactive terminal line by line so you can tell which command will throw the error. But I would go for a different tool as geopandas is not that mature. For this I would use PostGIS or SpatialLite.

Comment: @caiohamamura I'm looking into the link u sent. I think that the problem is a bug in the script though. What unit does shapely use for the tolerance of  the snapping? Since I used a projected coordinates system, I assumed it's "feet". Is it?

Comment: epsg:2227 seems to be in feets. But for the exit code you gave I'm pretty sure the error is due to exceeding limits for processing, I would go for another tool. As I said, geopandas is a new library. You could also try to execute the snapping for just the first row just to test. `snap(lines1.geometry[0], lines2_union, 10)`.

Comment: @caiohamamura I tried snapping for the first row and got this error now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Documents/Scripts/script.py", line 16, in <module>
    res.geometry = res.geometry.apply(snap(lines1.geometry[0], lines2_union, 10))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:63043)

Comment: TypeError: 'LineString' object is not callable
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @caiohamamura That exit code 1 problem is solved. Weird but it works now. The code is still the same I just used another .py file to run the script. The snapping though doesn't seem to work well. Just posted a screenshot above with a description

Comment: This is another issue. Shapely uses [GEOS Snap](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1operation_1_1overlay_1_1snap_1_1GeometrySnapper.html) you should open a new question asking why GEOS Snap algorithm doesn't work as expected. You should also provide shapefiles for testing.

Answer (score 3):

For this to work you will have to first unary_union lines2.geometry so that lines1 will snap to any line in lines2. And as snap isn't a vectorized function you will have to execute for each geometry using `apply`:

```
res = lines1
lines2_union = lines2.geometry.unary_union
res.geometry = lines1.geometry.apply(lambda x: snap(x, lines2_union, 10))
```

Comment: Thank u for ur quick answers! I tried what u suggested but i got nearly the same error as above except for the last line : AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom'
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Just saw ur edit! Will try what u suggested and get back to u

Comment: Didn't work :/ I'm still having that error AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom'

Comment: The error is in this line : res['geometry'] = snap(lines1['geometry'], lines2['geometry'], 10)

Comment: Yeah, that's because snap isn't vectorized, so you have to perform snap for each element of lines1 using apply as I edited.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following u. I thought that the second part u added is dependent to the first part. So u r saying that the snapping is performed like this : res = lines1
lines2_union = lines2.geometry.unary_union
res.geometry = lines1.geometry.apply(lambda x: snap(x, lines2_union, 10))
I tried that, now I have this error : Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: I'm gonna edit my code in my post above so u can see what I did.

Comment: Also what does lambda x refer to in apply ? P.S : I edited my post with the updated code

Comment: `apply` will run the function for each row. Actually you can change lambda function with ...apply(snap, True, [lines2_union, 10]), True will try to convert the result into the correct type for the output.